# Custom post type subtaxonomy template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called "Activities" with different taxonomies. One of this taxonomies has three subtaxonomies. 
Is there a template for single subtaxonomies only? And if yes, is there a way to display it in template hierarchy?

At this point taxonomy and subtaxonomies contents are displayed in the same taxonomy page.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean about sub-taxonomies.  Are you referring to the actual term?  If so you could use the following to template it:

**taxonomy-$taxonomy-$term.php**

An example of this would be if I had a taxonomy called genres and a term called horror, I could then template this as:

**taxonomy-genres-horror.php**

Refer to the template hierarchy for more:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/

Comment: Hello Chris, thanks for the reply. 
This is my hierarchy:

- **Activities** (custom post type)
- **Activities categories** (custom taxonomies)
- **What to see** (main taxonomy)
- **City** (sub taxonomy of What to see)

So the page hierarchy should be: 

taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}-{sub-term}.php

so 

activities_categories-what-to-see-city.php 


I would like to know if it's possible to create a page only for this subtaxonomy.

Comment: To be more clear I would like to know if it's possible to generate a page like this

taxonomy-genres-horror-subgenre.php

Thank you

Comment: I suppose the short answer would be no.  There isn't a way to assign a template in the hierarchy that way.  Organizationally, you may want to reconsider your approach.  However, if you need to, you could redirect the default generated page to a new one (like a 301) and build your own query based on the parameters you need.  Reference https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters for building your own query.